# Set different markers in pandas line plot

Tags: python, plot, marker

I have the following code which works for plotting three time series in different line styles:

```
styles = [ 'darkred', 'darkgreen', 'darkblue']

jacccard.T.plot(style=styles, marker='o')
plt.ylim(0.5, 1.0)
plt.xticks(range(len(jacccard.columns)), jacccard.columns)
plt.title('Jaccard Index for One-Mode and Two-Mode Networks', fontsize = 10)
plt.ylabel('Jaccard Index')
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
          fancybox=True, shadow=False, ncol=3)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Now I try to set, besides different line styles, different marker styles in the same:

```
styles = [ 'darkred', 'darkgreen', 'darkblue']
markers = [ '*', 'o', '.']

jacccard.T.plot(style=styles, marker=markers)
plt.ylim(0.5, 1.0)
plt.xticks(range(len(jacccard.columns)), jacccard.columns)
plt.title('Jaccard Index for One-Mode and Two-Mode Networks', fontsize = 10)
plt.ylabel('Jaccard Index')
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
          fancybox=True, shadow=False, ncol=3)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Unforunately, now I get the error message `ValueError: Unrecognized marker style ['*', 'o', '.']`even though I chose common marker styles. Can somebody please help?

Thanks!